# Read barcode via camera in an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application

Tags: mobile, camera, asp.net-mvc-5, barcode

I have created a web site with ASP.NET MVC 5. This web site is also available on mobile devices as a web app. But now I want to add the possibility for the user to scan barcodes with the mobile camera when they are using the app on their mobiles. Of course there are tools like phonegap that enable read barcodes, but the point is I want to add this functionality in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project.
So is there a way to read barcodes via the mobile camera in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: Try <input type="file" id="mypic" accept="image/*">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this issue and here is the solution:
In the view (**Index.chtml**):

```
     <form>
            <input type="file" class="upload" size="45" name="file" id="file">
    </form>
```

It is important to write the `<input type="file"...>` in a `form` tag.
Next I use the javascript. I use it because I want to call the controller as soon as the **Browse** button is clicked. You can use a submit button, too.
**Javascript:**

```
       $('#file').on("change", function () {
        for (i = 0; i < $('form').length; i++) {
            if ($('form').get(i)[0].value != "") /* get the file tag, you have to customize this code */
            {
                var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(i));
                CallService(formdata);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    function CallService(file) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Scan", "Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: file,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (barcode) {
                alert(barcode);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("ERROR");
            }
        });
    }
```

Next we have have analyse the image in the server and read the barcode of it. I am using the Aspose.BarCode Library:
**HomeController.cs**

```
        public JsonResult Scan(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string barcode = "";
        try
        {
            string path = "";
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }

            // Now we try to read the barcode
            // Instantiate BarCodeReader object
            BarCodeReader reader = new BarCodeReader(path, BarCodeReadType.Code39Standard);
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Width:" + img.Width + " - Height:" + img.Height);

            try
            {
                // read Code39 bar code
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    // detect bar code orientation
                    ViewBag.Title = reader.GetCodeText();
                    barcode = reader.GetCodeText();
                }
                reader.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception exp)
            {

                System.Console.Write(exp.Message);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Title = ex.Message;
        }
        return Json(barcode);


    }
}
```

Now the decoded barcode is returned to the view.

Comment: Hello Mo Prog, what do you used for barcode reader? BarCodeReader reader = new BarCodeReader(path, BarCodeReadType.Code39Standard); in this line. Can you please provide any reference for this?

Comment: @TruptiK.K. I used Aspose.Barcode for C# and it is working fine

Comment: @CodePope did you use a licensed version of this library?  I am also having an error with the above mentioned Comment.  BarCodeReaderType.Code39Standard is not recognized

Comment: @TruptiK.K. Did you ever get this to work?  I am having the exact same issue as you, I wonder if it is because I need a licensed version of the aspose.barcode library....

Comment: @dave317 Maybe it is too late for the reply, but yes, of course. It worked for me completely. And don't have any licensed version.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited code for to use Aspose.BarCode package ;

```
   public JsonResult ScanDelivered(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string readedBarcode = "";
        try
        {
            string path = "";
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }

          
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Width:" + img.Width + " - Height:" + img.Height);

            try
            {
                // Initialize barcode reader
                using (BarCodeReader reader = new BarCodeReader(path, DecodeType.AllSupportedTypes))
                {
                    // Recognize barcodes on the image
                    foreach (var barcode in reader.ReadBarCodes())
                    {
                       
                        readedBarcode = barcode.CodeText;
                    }
                }

            }

            catch (Exception exp)
            {

                System.Console.Write(exp.Message);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Title = ex.Message;
        }
        return Json(readedBarcode);


    }
```